# how to access subheader headers from pandas dataframe with multiple headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe with multiple headers

[image]

I want to get only AAPL columns with both High and Low. I tested that `data[['High', 'Low']]` which give me High and Low of all the Symbols but dont know how to filter it only for AAPL. Please advise.

Comment: `df.xs('AAPL',axis=1,level=1)` should do it , [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

Comment: perfect, many thanks.

Comment: No problem , For future reference [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) also please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) , it helps people test the data and your code.